# When a user who approved an edit is removed, an incorrect "-2 reverted" event appears in reputation history

Tags: bug, reputation, suggested-edits, reputation-history

I am aware that [I lose reputation for suggested edits if the final approver of the edit is removed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/311413). But now there is an extraneous "reverted" event to go along with user removal:

[image: reputation history]

Source: [my reputation history on Academia](https://academia.stackexchange.com/users/24055/walt?tab=reputation).

The edit was not reverted, it's [still there](https://academia.stackexchange.com/posts/88789/revisions). In any case, I should not lose 2 points *twice* for the total of -4. And indeed, my reputation only dropped from 131 to 129 despite what the history suggests.

So the line with "-2 reverted" is a bug.

---

A more extreme example: [Ben Miller on Sports](https://sports.stackexchange.com/users/1723/ben-miller?tab=reputation&sort=post) got 21 "reverted" events on 2017-06-30, none of which should be there. His rep loss is 42, not 84 as the reputation history says.

Comment: wth... A very rare bug

Comment: The same thing happened to me today on Sports.SE. I don't know which user was removed, but I lost 84 points today, 2 at a time, with 21 questions referenced.

Comment: @BenMiller That's how it's supposed to work though. Do you mean that you *also* saw one or more incorrect -2s that weren't actually removed from your rep?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie 21 edits overturned should result in a loss of 42 points. I lost 84 points. My rep history looks similar to the screenshot above: -2 for the reverted edit, and an additional -2 for user removed.

Comment: @BenMiller It [looks like you actually only lost 42](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/189/alltime/sports/2012-02-08/1723#1723) though. 6394 when the league was last updated, 6352 now.

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes, it looks like you are right. I only lost 42. The rep widget in the header is reporting a loss of 84.

Comment: @BenMiller D'oh, I didn't think to consider the math. That's clearer though, thanks. :) Definitely the same thing.

Comment: I see now that there was a high-rep former mod removed recently that apparently approved a lot of my early edits. I don't care about the rep loss, but this is a confusing bug.

Comment: Adding a "me too" comment. The same has just happened to me on Webmasters - https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users/288/chrisf?tab=reputation - not bothered about the reputation, but it struck me as odd when I saw the -4 this morning.